# Image map generated from gimp not working

Tags: html, image, imagemap

I generated this image map using gimp and when i added to code to my website it acts like there are no links there at all. Any reason why this might be happening.

```
<img src="images/footerlinks.jpg" width="175" height="66" border="0" usemap="#map"/>
<map name="map">
<!-- #$-:Image map file created by GIMP Image Map plug-in -->
<!-- #$-:GIMP Image Map plug-in by Maurits Rijk -->
<!-- #$-:Please do not edit lines starting with "#$" -->
<!-- #$VERSION:2.3 -->
<!-- #$AUTHOR:David -->
<area shape="rect" coords="32,72,239,415" nohref="nohref" /></area>
<area shape="rect" coords="393,320,483,336" href="http://www.dance-mate.com/details.html" /></area>
</map>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `areas` you define are outside the bounds of the image (image is 66px tall, first link has a top of 72px, second 320px). Order of the points in the rect shape is  `left, top, right, bottom`). Did you shrink the image, or did the Gimp really generate those areas outside the image bounds?

Also, [`area` is a void element (self closing)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/area.html), `nohref` isn't valid and make sure to add `alt` attributes to the links and image (image sized 7x in HTML so you can see the links):

```
<img src="images/footerlinks.jpg" width="1225" height="462" alt="foo" usemap="#map"/>
<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="32,72,239,415" href="#bar" alt="bar" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="393,320,483,336" href="#baz" alt="baz" />
</map>
```